# Generate sfdx-project.json

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I would like to create a new version of my package. I work with Jenkins so I clone my git repository once time ==> my `sfdx-project.json` is in default :

sfdx-project.json :

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "44.0"
}
```

How can I update my `sfdx-project.json` to use `sfdx force:package:version:create` ?

I would like a command to update my local `sfdx-project.json`

My error is like :

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  The package MyPackageName isn’t defined in the sfdx-project.json file. Add it to the packageDirectories section and add the alias to packageAliases with its 0Ho ID.

Answer (score 3):

Trudy is correct that you need to either
1. Create a package first (not a package version), OR
2. You need to have those details in your sfdx-project.json file.

This is what you have now:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "44.0"
}
```

But with a package created it should look something like this:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
      "package": "myPkgAlias",
      "versionName": "1.0.0",
      "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "46.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "myPkgAlias": "0Ho000000000000001"
  }
}
```

You need to provide the following properties in your package directory along with an alias to use for your package.

```
"package": "myPkgAlias",
"versionName": "1.0.0",
"versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
```

You also need the "packageAliases" section with at least one entry associating the package alias that you chose with the "0Ho*" package id.

```
"packageAliases": {
  "myPkgAlias": "0Ho000000000000001"
}
```

You can get the list of packages with the "0Ho*" package ids for your DevHub using:

```
sfdx force:package:list
```

Note that if your open project's sfdx-project.json file has a package alias defined it will show the alias in the returned list of packages.

See [Project Configuration File for Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm) in the Salesforce DX documentation for more information about the project file.

Answer (score 2):

It works the other way round:

The commands `sfdx force:package:create` and `sfdx force:package:version:create` will update your `sfdx-project.json` file automatically.

When you create the new version with Jenkins, you must push the changes to the git repository and pull the changes back to your local computer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create package before creating package version (as command below):

```
sfdx force:package:create --name dreamhouse --description "My Package" --packagetype Unlocked --path force-app --nonamespace --targetdevhubusername DevHub
```

Comment: I think you don't understand really my question. I'm on jenkins environment. My package as already be created but on other environnement. My sfdx-project.json on my machine is also not updated.